# Session no longer exists when resend WWW Unity3d and PHP

Tags: php, c, unity-game-engine, session

I created a system that sends the user id by Unity3D and on the server creates a session and sends the session back to the client (on Unity3D), so it all works! But when I send back from Unity3D to the server the session is simply gone! I already checked the browser and it works, it just does not work on Unity3D!
Does anyone have any idea what it is?

*C# on Unity3d*

```
void Start () {
   WWW w = new WWW (url+ "?id=" + userId);    
   StartCoroutine (SessionWWW (w));
}

private IEnumerator SessionWWW (WWW _w){
    yield return _w;  

    PlayerPrefs.SetString("cookie", _w.text);

    Debug.Log (PlayerPrefs.GetString("cookie"));
    Debug.Log (_w.text);
}

void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.P)) {
        string session= PlayerPrefs.GetString("cookie");
        WWW w = new WWW (url "?sessionid=" + session);    
        StartCoroutine (GetSessionWWW (w));
    }
}

private IEnumerator GetSessionWWW (WWW _w){
    yield return _w;  
    if (_w.text == "ok") {
        Debug.Log ("received!");
    } else {
        Debug.Log (_w.text);
    }
}
```

*PHP script:*

```
<?PHP
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $_SESSION['session'] = $id;
    echo $_SESSION['session'];
}
if(isset($_GET['sessionid'])){
    if(isset($_SESSION['session'])){
        echo $_SESSION['session'];
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: In the PHP script, after session_start() if you echo the session id before and after are the session IDs the same?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix In the browser works, it's the same, but Unity3D says "Notice: Undefined index: session in ..."

Comment: What cookies is Unity3D sending to the server?

Comment: In the first "if" of my PHP script I get the "echo" session, and in the second I send the session and Czech if this session exists, but it does not exist!

Answer (score 0):

If your wanting to set the session id of the current session in PHP use the function session_id($id) BEFORE session_start.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php

```
<?php

//do you need both of these?
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    session_id($id);
}
if(isset($_GET['sessionid'])){
    $sessionid = $_GET['sessionid'];
    session_id($sessionid);
}

session_start();

print_r($_SESSION)
?>
```

> `session_id ([ string $id ] ) : string`
>
> If id is specified, it will
>   replace the current session id. session_id() needs to be called before
>   session_start() for that purpose. Depending on the session handler,
>   not all characters are allowed within the session id. For example, the
>   file session handler only allows characters in the range a-z A-Z 0-9 ,
>   (comma) and - (minus)

you might also want to validate before setting the session id to prevent mistakes from your code and if this is on the internet other people can find it too.

(from the link above)

```
function session_valid_id($session_id)
{
    return preg_match('/^[-,a-zA-Z0-9]{1,128}$/', $session_id) > 0;
}


$id = $_GET['id'];
if (session_valid_id($id)) {
    session_id($id);
}
```

Comment: I edited the PHP code of the question, at first "if" I can create the session, however in the second "if" the session does not exist when I send a request from Unity3D to confirm that the session exists! Your code did not work! :(

Comment: can you show how you get the session the first time before this second call?

Comment: In the first "if" I create the session and I get it in Unity normally through "echo", but in the second "if" I get "Notice: Undefined index: session in ..."

Comment: session_id(sessionid); was missing a $: session_id($sessionid);

Comment: I was referring to my code, your code unfortunately did not work! :( I put "$"